# how to check if the value exists in the database from visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ado.net

I am making a web form which deletes the selected id from the database. But whenever I run my command I get the following error

> NullReferenceRxception was unhandled by the user.

And I'm getting this where I'm using addwithvalues.

This is my code:

```
con.Open();
string query = "delete from [User] where id ='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", TextBox1.Text); //this is giving an error
int UserExist = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (UserExist > 0)
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
else
{
    Label1.Text = "No such id found ";
}
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Are you sure the same id that you put in your textbox exits in your database? have you traced your code? Try this as well `TextBox1.Text.Trim()`

Comment: What is the Type of id in your database?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I am not an sql expert but if the problem really is in the line OP marked, does it even matter what is in the db or which type `id` is? Does `AddWithValue` access the db in any way? Couldn't the problem simply be that there is no `@id` in the query? (Which your answer solves, of course) @Valkyriee

Comment: @wkl yeah it can work that way as well. but this eliminates any unwanted data to be added as Id, a validation before sending to database.

Comment: @wkl here in delete it doesnt really matter, but in insert it'll be very useful ^^

Comment: Mark as answer if this was the answer you looked for

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach see if its works, i assumed the type of Id is an `Integer`

```
using(var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM User WHERE Id = @Id", conn))
{
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Int.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```